# Are there any methods to evaluate if draws of a specific lottery are truly random?

Tags: combinatorics, stochastic-processes, statistical-inference, chaos-theory

Just to be on the safe side this question is NOT about predicting winning numbers in a lottery etc.

I just wonder (since there are people that think that xyz lottery company does not reward jackpots at random etc) is there a way to prove that a specific lottery company indeed has a honest number picking scheme that is truly random by using data from past results (lets assume that we have a sample of 2000 past results)?

Or to put this in an other way suppose that a certain lottery company is indeed fraudulent and cherry picks a winner out of the database of participating tickets -by unknown to us criteria e.g they would like to pick a ticket that has a unique number combination which no other ticket has so that the jackpot never gets shared by more than 1 winner- by rigging the machine that outputs the numbered balls to result in a specific (and different each time) combination of numbers.

In the long run would any patterns emerge (by using 2000 previous drawing results) that would suggest that the resulting numbers are not truly random ?

Or is the sample too small to make such inference?

If it is possible to make such inference how exactly would you solve that problem?

Let's assume a powerball like lottery ticket scheme where you have to pick 5 numbers from 1 to 45 and additionally pick one number from 1 to 20.

so 5 (out of a group of 45) balls are drawn and then 1 (out of a separate group of 20) is drawn and in order for a ticket to win the jackpot it has to have all 5+1 numbers.

Comment: You have to model you problem in reality, so that it becomes a mathematical problem. In the real world, I think a lottery company has thousands of ways to cheat without leaving any mathematical flaw.

Comment: @WhatsUp such as?

Comment: Randomness can never be proven in practice. Only a strong derivation of a randomness can be shown (at least with a high probability). Take a dice. It is not possible to prove that it is fair, but if you make enough throws and the outcome is near the expected one, you have no reason to doubt the fairness. Whether a lottery company cheats is another thing. One last thing about lotteries : I think, the world would be much better without such jackpots whoever wins them.

Comment: @Peter I did not make a moral question ...my question is strictly about a mathematical solution, you can inference if a dice is fair even if you have a high-school degree you throw 2000 dices(or as dices approach infinity)and if the distribution of the results is not at least approximately even then the dice is not fair...And maybe if you have a PhD in one relative field such as I included as hashtags there are other ways to derive inference as well and that is what my question is all about I dont want to actually sue a company per se I wonder how one could approach this problem mathematically

Comment: At the risk of suggesting something obvious...  have you googled "randomness tests"?  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests) and [random.org](https://www.random.org/analysis/) are nice introductory articles with links to many actual techniques.  I don't know if these techniques are just for bit sequences or also for "choosing combos" like in a lottery.  My overall impression is that the math topic is quite specialized.  As for $2000$ past lottery results...  my (very layman) gut feel is that $2000$ is so small you can only catch cheating if they cheat stupidly.  :)